# Manage Facebook Page and Group without App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-group

I am writing code to manage my facebook page, corresponding inbox and a facebook group where I am admin. My requirements are

a) Monitor my facebook page inbox for new messages. When a new message is received, do some processing and verification of message and then post it to my group (preferable) (or page if group is not feasible).

b) Monitor messages on my group feed and flag messages which do not abide by certain rules. This will be a automated moderator.

As I understand, I will have to create a facebook app with permissions to manage page and groups, get it reviewed (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) to get access token with permissions to read page feed, page inbox and group feed. What should be the functionality of my app in this case so that it pass review?

Can this be achieved without creating an app or going through the review hassle? What I need is an access token and I can write a script achieve this without an app.

Comment: No app, no access token. _“What should be the functionality of my app in this case so that it pass review?”_ - well the functionality you need it to have. Whether or not that is an applicable use case, you’ll have to check with the documentation upfront.

Comment: The app that will be sent for review is supposed to have user facing functionality. Thats not my use case. I did not find any documentation on my use case.

Comment: It’s not about user-facing functionality alone any more, it is about what your app does with the data it gets access to. You will need to get it reviewed before you will be able to use it for this purpose.